# Frame 1:26 - What does q unify with?

Tags: scheme, reasoned-schemer

We have:

```lisp
(run* q
  (fresh (x)
    (== 
      `(,x)
      q)))
```

In this case  `` `(,x) `` is a list where the refrence to the variable `x` isn't quoted.

Does q unifies with a single element list?

Is the result `(_0)` because `q` unifies with the fresh variable `x` (even if it's in a list) or because it doesn't unify with anything at all? Or would in that case the result have been `()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does `q` unify with a single element list?

Yes. `(== (list x) q)` is the same as `(== q (list x))`. Both `q` and `x` are fresh before the execution of this unification goal (and `q` does not occur in `(list x)`). Afterwards, it is recorded in the substitution that the value of `q` is `(list x)`. No  value for `x` is recorded.

> Is the result `(_0)` because `q` unifies with the fresh variable `x` (even if it's in a list) or because it doesn't unify with anything at all? Or would in that case the result have been `()`?

No, `q` does not unify with `x`, but rather with a list containing `x`.

When the final value of the whole `run*` expression is returned, the variables are "reified", replaced with their values. `x` has no value to be replaced with, so it is printed as `_0`, inside a list as it happens, which list is the value associated with `q`.

The value of `(run* q ...)` is a list of all valid assignments to `q`, as usual. There is only one such association, for the variable `q` and the value `(list x)`.

So `( (_0) )`  should be printed as the value of the `(run* q ...)` expression -- a list of one value for `q`, which is a list containing an *uninstantiated* `x`, represented as a value `_0`.